# Is there any method than using message box because i'm creating a web application not a web form

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any method than using message box because i'm creating a web application not a window form ?

I'm still new in c# .Can anyone teach me how to solve it? I have been working it for couple hours but still has no idea on it.

```
    private void Button1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO contact.contacts(name,position,h/pno,company's name,address,post code,state,country,tel,did,fax,email) VALUES('" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtposition.Text + "'," + txthpno.Text + "','"+txtcompanyname.Text+"','"+txtaddress+"','"+txtpostcode.Text+"','"+txtstate.Text+"','"+txtcountry.Text+"','"+txttel.Text+"','"+txtdirect.Text+"','"+txtfax.Text+"',"+txtemail.Text+")";
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);

        try

        {
            if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Not Inserted");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        connection.Close();

    }
}
```

}

i expect it can come out with Data inserted message when i store the data

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i expect it can come out with Data inserted message when i store the data

Comment: Response.Write("<script>alert('Hello World');</script>");

Comment: Even in a desktop application you wouldn't display messageboxes from a data access method. You'd use logging, return an error value or throw an exception and let the *top-level* method decide how to talk to the user. That's typically done by displaying a message on the form itself, warning indicators etc. You can do the same in your web app. Mesage boxes with raw exception messages aren't useful

Comment: The classical equivalent to a forms-messagebox is an alert.

Comment: You can have a label on your page. Example label1. Then assign the message to label1.Text. It will display on your webpage.

Comment: Unrelated: Use sqlParameters, at the least.

Comment: In all stacks (Winforms, WPF, Webforms, ASP.NET MVC and later) there are validator controls, validation summary controls etc that can be used to notify that something went wrong. I suggest you start with a tutorial or course for the web stack you target. Both Microsoft and Pluralsight offer a lot of tutorials, walkthroughs and free courses that show how to properly handle errors, how to log them and how to talk to the user when appropriate

Comment: You can get 3 months free access to Pluralsight's courses through the (also free) Visual Studio Dev Essentials program. Microsoft has several progams for students too. Gettting in contact with your local .NET Meetup or student branch is another good idea. The code you posted has several issues, like using a connection without a `using` block, string concatenation to create SQL queries, exposing yourself to SQL injection etc.

Comment: Imagine what would happen if someone typed `'; drop table contact.contacts;--` in the Email field. [This is a famous example](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: You can use the Windows messagebox in any application by doing following 1) from Menu : Project : Add Reference : Net : PresentationFrameWork  2) Add library to top of module : using System.Windows;

Comment: I use Oracle, but MySQL should be somewhat similar. Can you really have a column name like `Company's Name` , and `h/pno` ? Or is this pseudo code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a web application you should output messages in HTML, obviously. Generate a `<p>` element, or a `<span>`, with the message.

If you use a framework, e.g. ASP.NET, you can use the Designer to place a `Label` on your `Form`, then, in Code-Behind, assign the message text to `Label`.Text property. But there are many frameworks, so you might be using something else. Your sample code looks like ASP.NET, though, so I added that tag to the question.

By the way, it is good practice to use `using` block for the connection.

BTW2: use SQL variables to avoid SQL injection!!!

Also, you don't want to use MessageBox or `alert` boxes too often, because these are annoying, and the common browser will propose to block those. Certainly not for regular `OK` messages. Create proper message fields in your web page instead.

Summary: web design is fun but complex, so get your hands on some books on: C#, HTML, ASP, SQL

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly Do correction of your SQL query and parameter

and Yes we can use other things in asp.net web app instead of `MessageBox`

```
MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted");
```

you can use

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Data Inserted');", true);
```

[ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Even you can also use other JavaScript plugins to show alerts